# Parent child relationship sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how can I design my database with the following requirements below?

- I have a table named "Application"
- For each record on the "Application" table, one application record could be a parent of multiple application record on application table.

I am thinking to create a new table "Application relation", with fields parent_app_id and child_app_id, both referencing to application_id? can I do that?

Any help or ideas will be much appreciated

Comment: just create a column in your main table with a primary key auto increment then in your new table you create a column varchar and in there you put the id from the main key, so that you can refer to them easily

Comment: is this a valid way? thanks

Comment: i have a table class inside my key is classno then a table customer and inside my key is customerno then a booked classes table with a key bookno so when a customer book a class i simply insert my key for the customer and the key for the class they book into booked classes table

Comment: The foreign key should be the same type as the column it refers to. An auto increment field is typically an unsigned int, not varchar. For your use, add a column \`parent_id\`, with a type of int(11) unsigned. If you do not already have a auto incrementing primary key field, add one with the same type. If parents can have multiple children, but children can only have one parent, there isn't a need for a linking table.

Comment: HI @SloanThrasher I already have an auto incrementing id in application table. I didn't get why I don't need to have another table?

Comment: You have a one to many relationship. The additional table would enable a many to many relationship. Unless a child can have more than one parent, you don't need that table.

Answer (score 0):

As @SloanThrashe stated on his comment to be clear

```
 CREATE TABLE Application(
    application_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    application_name varchar(50)  NOT NULL,
    fk_application_id int NULL,   
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
 );

 Insert into Application(application_id, application_name, fk_application_id) 
    values (1, 'HR', null), (2, 'Timesheet',1), (3,'Leave Request', 1);
```

**Select Statement**

```
 Select p.application_id PID
        , p.application_name Parent_App
        , c.application_name Child_App
 From Application p
 Inner join Application c on p.application_id = c.fk_application_id
```

**SQL Result**

```
 PID   Parent_App   Child_App
 1     HR           Timesheet
 1     HR           Leave Request
```